# Karate API : Passing variables to other feature file is not working

Tags: karate

I am calling login feature file from other feature file from where I am passing url, username and password but it is not working for me. I am not using Background key here and i do not want also.

```
 @CallAnotherFeature
 Feature: Call Login Feature

 Scenario: Calling Login Test
 * def config = { endPointURL: 'https://qa1.testurl.com/login',username: 'user123', password: 'password123' }
* def result= call read('Login.feature') config
* print result.response
* print 'Sign In-'+signIn
* print 'Sign In Reponse-'+signIn.response


Feature:  Login Feature

Scenario: Test Login for different users

* print 'Starting Test','#(endPointURL)'
Given url '#(endPointURL)'
* print 'user name','#(username)'
* print 'Password ','#(password)'
#And form field username = '#(username)'
#And form field password = '#(password)'
And request { username: '#(username)', password: '#(password)'}
When method post
Then status 200
* print response
* match response.loginSuccess == true
```

In Login.feature I tried to pass username and password as form data also even though these did not work. Could someone tell me what mistake I am making here.

I am using latest karate version 0.9.0

Comment: can you please elaborate more about what is the error you are getting or what did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few issues in your scripts,

**1. Call Login Feature**

1.1) I don't see `signIn` variable initialized anywhere in this feature nor from your `login feature` but you are trying to print it.

1.2) `=` Should be placed properly ;)

```
* def result = call read('Login.feature') config
```

**2. Login Feature**

2.1) I think you misunderstood the concept of embedded expressions. only for templating it into a JSON you may use it. but for calling it you can simply use the variable name.

eg.

```
Given url endPointURL
And form field username = username
And request { username: '#(username)', password: '#(password)'}
```

***NOT***

```
Given url '#(endPointURL)'
And form field username = '#(username)'
```

I will be more clear for you if you read the karate documentation from here -> [karate Doc](https://github.com/intuit/karate) and refer [karate Demos](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo)

Comment: Thank you so much. I referred below examples
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature/called-normal.feature   https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature/call-feature.feature

Comment: is there any restriction that the def variable would not work with the Given keyword.